# Debugging Tensorflow hang on global variables initialisation

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm after advice on how to debug what on Tensorflow is struggling with   when it hangs.

I have a multi layer CNN which hangs upon global_variables_initializer() is run in the session. I am getting no errors or messages on the console output.

Is there an intelligent way of debugging what Tensorflow is struggling with when it hangs instead of repeatedly commenting out lines of code that makes the graph, and re-running to see where it hangs. Would TensorFlow debugger (tfdbg) help? What options do I have?

Ideally it would be great to just to break current execution and look at some stack or similar to see where the execution is hanging during the init.

I'm currently running Tensorflow 0.12.1 with Python 3 inside a Jupiter notebook.

Comment: When debugging tensorflow do keep in mind that the C++ part of tensorflow might spit out some warnings/error messages to standard output which your jupyter notebook will note capture/display.

Comment: @amo-ej1 I have done what you have suggested. This unocerd a few typo error as well. The problem still exists, but now I also have one more clue, the python tensorflow exists with return code 137 and the SIGKILL (9) signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. The tip from @amo-ej1 to run in a regular file was a step in the correct direction. This uncovered that the tensor flow process was killing itself off with a SIGKILL and returning an error code of 137.

I tried Tensorflow Debugger *tfdbg* though this did not provide any further details as the problem was the graph did not initialize. I started to think the graph structure was incorrect, so I dumped out the graph structure using:
`tf.summary.FileWriter('./logs/traing_graph', graph)`

I then used up Tensorboard to inspect the resultant summary graph structure data dumped out the the directory and found that the tensor dimensions of the Fully Connected layer was wrong , having a width of 15million !!?! (*wrong*)

It turned out that one of the configurable parameters of the graph was incorrect. It was picking the dimension of the layer 2 tensor shape  incorrectly from an incorrect addressing the previous tf.shape type property and it exploded the dimensions of the graph.

There were no OOM error messages in /var/log/system.log so I am unsure why the graph initialisation caused the python tensorflow script process to die.

I fixed the dimensions of the graph and graph initialization worked just fine!

My top tip is visualise your graph with Tensorboard before initialisation and training to do a quick check the resultant graph structure you coded it what you expected it to be. You probably will save yourself a lot of time! :-)

Answer (score 0):

A common methodology to debug tensorflow is to replace the placeholders and/or variables with numpy arrays and put them inside tf.const. When you do so you can actually examine the logic of your code by setting a breakpoints and to see numbers in "pythoninc" and not just tensors. It will be much easier to help you if you would post your code here, but here is a dummy example:

```
 with tf.name_scope('scope_name'):
    ### This block is for debug only
    import numpy as np
    batch_size = 20
    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(tf.tables_initializer())
    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init_op)
    ### End of first debug block

    ## Replacing Placeholders for debug - uncomment the placehlolders and  comment the numpy arrays to producation mode
    const_a = tf.constant((np.random.rand(batch_size, 26) > 0.85).astype(int), dtype=tf.float32)
    const_b = tf.constant(np.random.randint(0, 20, batch_size * 26).reshape((batch_size, 26)), dtype=tf.float32)
    # real_a_placeholder = tf.log(input_placeholder_dict[A_DATA])
    # real_b_placeholder = tf.log(input_placeholder_dict[B_DATA])

    # dummy opreation
    c = a - b

    # selecting top k - in the sanity check you can see here that you actullay get the top items and top values
    top_k = 5
    top_k_values, top_k_indices = tf.nn.top_k(c,
                                                                                    k=top_k, sorted=True,
                                                                                    name="top_k")
    ## Replacing Variable for debug - uncomment the variables and comment the numpy arrays to producation mode
```

Now, run your code with breakpoints and you have 2 options to see the values in the debugger:
1.**sess.run(*palceholder_name*)**
2.you can use eval - **varaible_name.eval(sessnio=sess)**

Comment: I tried your suggestion, though I have localised the error to be exactly at the tf.global_variables_init(). Tensorflow exits with a return code of 137 and SIGKILL 9.

Comment: 1.Can you share your code? 2. Did you try to run it as a regular python file and not Ipython notebook?

Comment: *I used python 2.7 (no Ipython)
@neurozen please share your code so I can help you debug it.